# Cloud Storage - Copy from PVC to Bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil, kubernetes-pvc, gcsfuse

I currently have a PVC (old one, with no dynamic storage size) on my GCP architecture.

I want to migrate everything from that PVC to a new bucket. I already have the bucket up and running and ready to replace the PVC.

The thing is that I have many folders and sub-folders on my current PVC, so handly copy the folders and files will take too long and cause some errors along the way probably.

I looked into the `gsutil` commands, looked like it might work but I don't see a way to copy all the content of my PVC (and to keep the current organization of that PVC).

Thanks,

Comment: Did you have a look to gsutil rsync?

Comment: Yes I saw that, i'll give it a try, looks pretty neat thx !

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere looks like it might work with rsync, just need to find a way to run the command from my local environment to access the distant PVC, something like : ```gsutil -m rsync -cdr web-xxxx-xxx:/var/www/html/files gs://example-bucket```

Comment: I think you need to claim your volume and then to execute the command, thus in a Pod runtime context

Answer (score 0):

Ok so a few days later, a solution came up by searching how to transfer not between a PVC to a bucket but between a POD to a bucket, I found the [SKBN](https://github.com/maorfr/skbn) tool which does that.

It's plugged with most of the storage systems (S2, GCS, ...) and work like a charm : `skbn cp --src k8s://namespace/podName/containerName/path --dst gcs://bucketName`

It also works for the other way around, copying date from a bucket to a pod, if necessary.